# How to override a Language.properties from a theme?

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

I added new configuration settings to my Liferay theme inside the file **liferay-look-and-feel.xml**

```
<setting configurable="true" key="show-navigation" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

In the control panel I can see the setting with `show-navigation` label.
I want to translate it to *Show the Main Navigation* using `Language.properties` inside the theme.
Then to accomplish this in my theme I added this files (`theme\docroot\WEB-INF\src\content`):

- Language.properties
- Language_en.properties
- Language_fr.properties

Which each file contains the translation as so:

```
show-navigation=Show the Main Navigation
```

then in `theme\docroot\WEB-INF\` I added **liferay-hook.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_2_0.dtd">

<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
    <language-properties>content/Language*.properties</language-properties>
</hook>
```

But it doesn't work. If I perform the same procedure for a portlet it works.
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the name: You don't use `content/Language*.properties`, but just `content/Language.properties`. Otherwise I believe you're on the correct way to solve the problem, it's just this little detail